# php - "Undefined type 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer'.intelephense(1009)" when in vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, error-handling, phpmailer

I'm currently trying to setup a simple PMP mailer script, however I'm getting an error "Undefined type 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer'.intelephense(1009)" on line 14 of the code. So the code cannot be ran yet.

I started using PMPMailer last night and not really sure how to solve this problem. Could the problem be that my PHPMailer is in a different drive? To clarify I am trying to use this code in Visual Studio Code.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];

    require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    //smtp settings
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "youremail@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = 'yourpassword';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

    //email settings
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress("youremail@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject = ("$email ($subject)");
    $mail->Body = $body;

    if($mail->send()){
        $status = "success";
        $response = "Email is sent!";
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "failed";
        $response = "Something is wrong: <br>" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

    exit(json_encode(array("status" => $status, "response" => $response)));
}
```

Comment: your problem is `Intelephense`

Comment: Are you sure the PHPMailer is in the same directory as this file? If so, sometimes you need to reload VS Code for it to index intelephense correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found was Intelephense simply giving me a false error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).